# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I had to copy all of my ASP>NET MVC5 project to a new project and after that when i try to run it i am getting this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept' or one
>   of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have done some research but could not find anything about it also i deleted the content of whole bin file, cleaned the project and done rebuild but it didnt work. I am new to MVC5 and dont know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the assembly reference in the References folder..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you manually removed Microsoft appInsights dlls from your project and tried to add it back?. You need to also install `Microsoft ApplicationInsights Instrumenation Intercept Extension` nuget package where that dll is contained.